# How to use a method from another form?

Tags: c#, methods

I have a method called SendOutput, which is in a form called Output. This is what it contains:

```
public void SendOutput()
{
    richTextBox1.Text = "\n[-] General Event | Maybe a button click?\n";
}
```

How can I make this method to where it will work across multiple forms? E.x.:

```
string txt = fastColoredTextBox1.Text;
SendToPipe(txt.ToString);
SendOutput();
```

(That would be in a different form from which the method was called in)

Comment: You can make it a static member of Output. And then call it thus: `Output.SendOutput()`. Better still, if it's not logically a member of that form, why not put it another *perhaps static* class?

Comment: @AAA Changing it to public static void created errors.

Comment: What is `SendToPipe(txt.ToString);`? Is it important in this question? And what does "How can I make this method to where it will work across multiple forms?" mean to you? It's not clear form the question.

Comment: Is `richtextBox1` loacated on the current form or on the `Output` form only?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a seperate class that only contains the method SendOutput. Have the new class you created that only contains SendOutput and have it return the data that you're wanting to use. You can them populate the richTextBox1 field based on the data you return from your seperate SendOutput class, in your form class.

I ran into the same issue trying to populate a dataGridView in my current project. I had to use "return" to get the data back to my form class. Once I did that, I was then able to populate my dataGridView in my form class.

Hopefully this make sense, I'm typing all this from my phone and I don't usually answer questions.

Answer (score -1):

As you use instance level field `richTextBox1` inside of the method you cannot make it static. To call non-static method you need to have a reference to the instance of the class where it is declared, eg Form. You can pass reference of the form through the static property for example:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static Form1 CurrentFormInstance { get; private set; }

        public Form1() => InitializeComponent();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            CurrentFormInstance = this;
        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) =>
            CurrentFormInstance = null;

        public void SendOutput() =>
            richTextBox1.Text = "\n[-] General Event | Maybe a button click?\n";
    }
```

When this form opened, it initializes `CurrentFormInstance` with `this`. After that you can access its instance from any other place in your program

```
Form1.CurrentFormInstance?.SendOutput()
```

Comment: `public static Form1 CurrentFormInstance { get; private set; }` is a terrible idea as a new instance of the `Form1` will overwrite an existing one.